# Ionic-angular mobile app with headless browser

Tags: ionic-framework, webdriver, puppeteer, ui-automation, google-chrome-headless

I am currently working on creating a small Ionic mobile app to automate car park bookings. We have a separate car park booking website, and the objective is to develop a mobile app that enables users to reserve a car park slot.

The app should allow users to input their desired car park slot and then load the car park booking website in the background using a headless browser. It will perform a search for the specified car park slot and click the reserve button in the background (without user interactions). Then, displays a successful message in the UI.

I have attempted to automate this process within the Ionic app using Puppeteer, Taiko, and Selenium WebDriver, but unfortunately, I have not been successful. While these frameworks are commonly used for browser automation, they may not be directly compatible with Ionic.

To achieve our goal, what framework/tool I I should use with ionic framework?

Appreciate any help/suggestions